# Trouble with Multiple API Calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx-effects

I'm having some issues with a ngrx effect I wrote which is supposed to retrieve information via multiple API calls. For some reason it is randomly retrieving some calls successfully but others, it is just returning as null.

**Effect:**

```
 @Effect()
  loadMoveList$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(pokemonActions.PokemonActionTypes.SetSelectedGame),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store$.select(pokemonSelectors.getMoveLists), 
      this.store$.select(pokemonSelectors.getSelectedGame),
      ),
    map(([action, moveLists, selectedGame])=> {
      let newMoveList = []
      if(moveLists[selectedGame][0].moveInfo === null){
        moveLists[selectedGame].map(_move=>{
          newMoveList.push({..._move, moveInfo: this.pokemonService.getMove(_move.moveUrl)}as Move)
        })
      }
      const newMoveLists = {...moveLists, [selectedGame]: newMoveList} as MoveLists
      return new pokemonActions.LoadMoveListSuccess(newMoveLists)
    })
  )
```

**service getMove() code:**

```
getMove(moveUrl:string):Observable<MoveInfo>{
    if(this.movesCache[moveUrl]){
      return this.movesCache[moveUrl];
    }
    else{
      this.movesCache[moveUrl] = this.httpClient.get<MoveInfo>(moveUrl).pipe(
        shareReplay(1),
        catchError(err=>{
          delete this.movesCache[moveUrl];
          console.log(err);
          return EMPTY;
        }));
    }
  }
```

Comment: I see few issues in the service and effect, before i can provide a solution i want to understand
how you can `map` over `moveLists[selectedGame]` if the `moveLists[selectedGame][0].moveInfo === null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will refactor the service method getMove(),

```
return this.movesCache[moveUrl];
```

is not returning an observable and in your else block you are not returning the result of the http get call.

Refactored Service method

```
getMove(moveUrl:string):Observable<MoveInfo>{
    if(this.movesCache[moveUrl]){
      return of(this.movesCache[moveUrl]);
    }
    else{
      return this.httpClient.get<MoveInfo>(moveUrl).pipe(
        tap(move => this.moveCache[moveUrl] = move),
        catchError(err=>{
          delete this.movesCache[moveUrl];
          console.log(err);
          throwError(err.message)
        }));
    }
  }
```

Refactor the effect.

```
 @Effect()
  loadMoveList$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(pokemonActions.PokemonActionTypes.SetSelectedGame),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store$.select(pokemonSelectors.getMoveLists), 
      this.store$.select(pokemonSelectors.getSelectedGame),
      ),
    switchMap(([action, moveLists, selectedGame])=> {
      let apiCalls = [];
      if(moveLists[selectedGame][0].moveInfo === null) {
        apiCalls = [moveLists[selectedGame].map(_move=> this.pokemonService.getMove(_move.moveUrl)]
        return forkJoin(...apiCalls).pipe(
          map((response) => {
            let newMoveLists = moveLists[selectedGame].map((_move, index) => {
              return { ..._move, moveInfo: response[index] }
            })
            return new pokemonActions.LoadMoveListSuccess(newMoveLists)
          })
        )
      } else {
        const newMoveLists = {...moveLists, [selectedGame]: []} as MoveLists
        return new pokemonActions.LoadMoveListSuccess(newMoveLists)
      }
    })
  )
```